# How do I convert the DataFrame's Date object to a datetime format for plotting?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I am using a data set from Yahoo Finance, about stock market data. I wanted to plot the close price of the stock vs. the date range. On the X-Axis I wanted the date values and on the Y-axis I wanted the close price.

This is the data frame I have:

|  | Date | Close | Adj Close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 03/04/2006 | 19.267448 | 9.831543 |
| 1 | 04/04/2006 | 19.413416 | 9.906025 |
| 2 | 05/04/2006 | 20.218927 | 10.317053 |
| 3 | 07/04/2006 | 19.899965 | 10.154296 |
| 4 | 10/04/2006 | 19.564787 | 9.983268 |

The data types used are:

- Date: object
- Close: float64
- Adj Close: float64
- dtype: object

I plot I got was:
[The plot of the close price, where X-Axis has numbers from 0 - 3500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnQzG.png)

**dataframe name**:df
**column name**: Close

> I tried the following code:

`df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f')`and got: `ValueError: time data '03/04/2006' does not match format '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f' (match)`

> I also tried:

`df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)` and got a `ParserError: Unknown string format: 03/04/200604/04/2006`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

without `format` parameter. Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['03/04/2006', '05/04/2006']})
pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

output:

[image]